# SDL doesn't display fullscreen on iPhone 5/6/6+

Tags: ios, iphone, sdl-2

Running SDL's demo, I notice the screen on iPhone 5/5s, iPhone 6/6 Plus are not display in fullsize. There are black bars on top and bottom of the screen. SDL display 320×480 regardless of what phone simulator was chosen.

Here's the print-out of `SDL_uikitappdelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Screen size: (%f, %f)", [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds.size.height);
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f",
          NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
}

2014-10-11 17:09:21.267 Happy[18363:725719] Screen size: (640.000000, 960.000000)
2014-10-11 17:09:21.268 Happy[18363:725719] Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7feab951f1a0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7feab9619420; size = 640.000000 x 960.000000>>, scale: 2.000000, nativeScale: 2.000000
```

Note that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` executes before `SDL_init()` and `SDL_CreateWindow()`.

I'm expecting the following iPhone screen size:

```
iPhone5 = 320x568, 
iPhone6 = 375x667, 
iPhone6 Plus = 414x736
```

Anyone has thoughts as to why and how to make it fullscreen?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was just fighting this same thing when I found your post. The issue was that the Xcode project file template included with SDL was from pre-Xcode 6, and a bunch of settings were requiring launch images for the various screen sizes to hint that the iPhone 5 and up were supported.

Obviously, proceeding with that would be a brittle solution. I created a new empty project and am using the iOS 8 LaunchScreen.xib without any launch images. This allows the app to support any screen size (tested with resizable iPhone simulator).